# Issue in importing nineoldandroids v4 support library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, nineoldandroids

I am trying to use the nineoldandroids v4 support library to support fragment animations. Here is the [library](https://github.com/kedzie/Support_v4_NineOldAndroids). I want to add it as a library. But when I added I got an error

```
Error:(13, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'getAndroidPrebuilt()'!

Possible causes could be:  
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (<a href="open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)
  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)
  - or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)
```

I am not sure whats going wrong, could someone help please?

Thanks